# c# how to inclued a pdf file to my windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, directory

When i publish my windows application for a cd/usb , i want that pdf iclueded with application. And when install the program, pdf must copied to user's computer. Then i must know the pdf file's directory for click event. What should i do?

Note: I'm sorry for my bad english. I hope that explain my problem.

Here's picture from my app;

[image]

After edited;

```
pdfFullPath = Path.GetFullPath("Kullanım Kılavuzu.pdf");
```

and my buttons like;

```
 private void btnFirma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfFullPath);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the pdf file and click properties, then in the properties window set the following properties:

```
Build Action: Content

Copy to Output Directory: Copy always
```

After publishing your app, the file will be at this path:

```
string pdfFullPath = Path.GetFullPath("Kullanım Klavuzu.pdf");
```

Comment: It's ok. When publish i can see pdf file. But i can't reach pdf file after than installation. I edited my question. You can check my codes.

Comment: Is your file name Kullanım Klavuzu? Or is it Kullanım Kılavuzu? I am editing my answer

Comment: Kullanım Klavuzu.pdf is document's name

Comment: And please don't remember to mark as aswer if it works :)

Answer (score 2):

As Oguz said, ensure that the PDF is included in the build path first.

If your executable is always going to be in a fixed directory structure. So you will know where the pdf is in relation to the application. You can try:

```
string pdfFullPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\document\\Kullanım Kılavuzu.pdf";
```

Almost forgot your working directory might be off.

In your button click try:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = pdfFullPath;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\document";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Not possible without the step 1 in my answer

Comment: Very True, he would have to include the PDF into the build path